# What will be my point of failure if I am receiving UDP data faster than my program can process?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, udp

I have simple python script to receive data from UDP socket, combine 500 UDP data (~4 KB each) together and post that data to Curl endpoint. At small scale of approx 100 UDP/Second my program works.

```
import socket
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005
mylist = []
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
   data, addr = sock.recvfrom(4096) 
   mylist.add(data)

   if len(mylist) == 500:
       # change mylist to json logic
       curl XPOST 'Endpoint' --mylist 'application/json' # Basically Curl Xpost the data to endpoint.
       del mylist[:]
```

My question here is

1. If I have UDP data coming in at higher rate ~ 3k-4k UDP/Second, will I run out of RAM? Disk Space? eth? Will I lose UDP while I CURL the data to endpoint?
2. How do I address these problems? Get more RAM, Disk, eth? Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: `mylist = list []` does not look like python.

Comment: @Goyo Changed! Code snippet to give an overview of what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 2):

You won't run out of RAM since you only hold a maximum of 500 packets in memory at a time. Disc space is completely irrelevant. If your application processes the data slower than the packets arrive the operating system will buffer them. However, at some point the buffer is full and packets will be dropped. You can configure the buffer size but that won't help if they continuously arrive at a higher rate than you process them. The only way not to lose UDP packets is by making your application fast enough.